# Integral of $\exp(-r^2)/r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-calculus, hydrogen, ground-state

I came across the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1r\exp(-2\lambda r^2)\mathrm dr
$$
in variational method for hydrogen method when choosing the test wavefuntion as
$$
\psi=\exp(-\lambda r^2)
$$
since there is a $\frac1r$ in the potential.

How to compute it?

Comment: I’m betting you are missing an $r^2$ factor from the volume element $r^2\sin\theta dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$ in spherical.

Comment: Maybe that should be $\int_0^\infty\frac1r\exp(-2\lambda r^2)\mathrm dV$ where $dV = 4\pi r²dr$ ?

Comment: Thank you both, and I'm a fool. : )

Comment: … or just tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It diverges at $0$, so you cannot compute it. See the comments, too. It may have been set up incorrectly.